# Why is the limit of a real sequence defined so?

Tags: limits

So I read in Mathematical Analysis Zorich - 1 that "the limit of a real sequence  $f:\Bbb N \to \Bbb R$ is $A \in \Bbb R$" is defined as follows:

$$\Bigl (\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} f_n=A \Bigr ) := \forall V(A)\ \exists N\in \Bbb N\ \ \forall n>N(f_n \in V(A))$$ (where$\ V(A)$ is some neighbourhood of $A$)
$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$or
$$\Bigl (\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} f_n:=A \Bigr ) := \forall \epsilon >0 \ \exists N\in \Bbb N\ \ \forall n>N\ (|f_n - A|< \epsilon)$$
While I understand how to apply the definition to find the limits of sample sequences, my questions are:

### -Why is this defined so?

### -What's the idea here?

### -What's the intuition that led to this definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An English description of limit is that: $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n = A$ provided values of $f_n$ can be made arbitrarily close to $A$ by taking $n$ sufficiently large.

What does *arbitrarily close to $A$* mean?  It means *as close as you want*.  If you measure “closeness”  by distance, it means “within $\epsilon$, no matter how small $\epsilon$ is, as long as it's positive.”

What does *sufficiently large* mean?  It means *after a certain number of terms have passed*.  So after some threshold index $N$.

To put this together, the definition of limit might be phrased as: “Pick any small number you want.  Call it $\epsilon$.  I can find a corresponding threshold index, which I'll call $N$, after which sequence terms $a_n$ are within $\epsilon$ of $A$.”

I hope that at least partially answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have an intuitive idea of a limit of a sequence $x_n\rightarrow x$:

1. The easiest case is if the sequence just gets closer and closer to $x$ in an obvious way, like the sequence $x_n \equiv 2+\frac{1}{n}$.
2. But of course you don't mind if the sequence is sometimes bigger and sometimes smaller than the limit $x$, as long as it still gets closer, like the sequence $$x_n = 2 + \frac{1}{n}(-1)^n,$$ which goes back and forth around 2.
3. And you wouldn't mind if it sometimes gets farther from $x$, as long as it eventually homes in on $x$, as in the sequence :$$x_n = \begin{cases}n^3 &\text{ if }n\leq 1000\\ 2+\frac{1}{n}&\text{ if }n > 1000\end{cases}$$
   which gets very, very large and far from 2 before homing in on 2.

Now here are some situations you'd like to avoid:

4. If the sequence grows without limit, as with the sequence $x_n = 4n$.
5. If the sequence keeps waving around without landing anywhere, as in the sequence $x_n = (-1)^n$, which goes back and forth between -1 and 1.
6. If the sequence gets closer and closer to a value, *but never gets close enough*. This happens for sequences like:
   $$x_n = (-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{n}\right)$$

   Take a look at this sequence (plot it if you like). Every term in this sequence is closer to 0 than the term before it. The sequence gets monotonically closer and closer to 0. But it never gets closer than within $\frac{1}{8}$ of 0. It's always at arm's length. Since it never gets extremely close (only relatively close), we don't want to say that the limit of this sequence is 0.
7. If the sequence gets closer and closer to a value— as close as you'd like — but keeps jumping away:
   $$x_n = \begin{cases}2 + \frac{1}{n} &\text{ if }n\text{ is odd}\\ 3+\frac{1}{n}&\text{ if }n\text{ is even}.\end{cases}$$
   Take a look at this sequence: if you look at just the odd terms, it looks like it goes to 2. If you look at just the even terms, it looks like it goes to 3. In fact, it bounces back and forth between them. But we don't want to say the sequence has two limits— instead we want to say that the sequence has no limit, because every time it gets close to 2, it gets pulled away to 3, and vice-versa.

To capture all of these criteria in the definition of limit, we define limit as follows:

> **Definition (Limit)**: If the limit of the sequence $x_n$ is $x$, then every circle we draw around $x$ should contain a complete *tail* of the sequence $x_n$. We should always be able to find a complete tail of the sequence that fits in the circle no matter how small the circle is.

(A tail of a sequence is any part of the sequence starting at any term in the middle and continuing on forever. So for example, $\{x_5, x_6, x_7, \ldots\}$.)

(The focus is on small circles, because we care about the sequence getting very *close* to $x$, fitting within a small circle around $x$.)

This definition includes all of the cases we mentioned where we'd like to have limits, and excludes all of the exceptions:

1. If the sequence gets closer and closer to $x$, it'll allow us to draw smaller and smaller circles. We can draw circles no matter how small.
2. If the sequence is sometimes bigger and sometimes smaller, but still gets closer and closer to $x$, we'll just draw a circle with room on the left and room on the right.
3. If the sequence goes wild initially but eventually goes to $x$, this means that *some* tail of the sequence is eventually close to $x$. We'll just choose a tail starting somewhere after the sequence has finished going wild. Those points will all be close to $x$.
4. If the sequence grows without limit, then eventually it'll be far away from $x$, and stay far away from $x$ forever. This means that the tail of the sequence will be far away from $x$. This means that we can draw a small circle around $x$, and the tail won't be within that circle because it will be far away, which proves that the sequence doesn't have $x$ as a limit.
5. If the sequence keeps waving around between several spots, then its tail keeps waving around. As a result, there's a circle we can draw which contains one spot the sequence waves to, and doesn't contain the other spot. Hence the tail of the sequence doesn't fit within that circle, so the limit of the sequence isn't in that circle.
6. If the sequence never gets close enough to $x$, we can draw a small circle around $x$ which the sequence never enters. Hence the tail never enters the circle. Hence the limit isn't in the circle, and the limit isn't $x$.
7. If the sequence gets close to several points, then we have a case like (5).